# Algorithm of searching for a pair of integers in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, divide-and-conquer

I'm quite new to algorithm and I encountered a question to which my approach does not works properly. **Here's the precondition**:

You are given a list  `L=[(a1,b1),…,(an,bn)]`  of n pairs of integers. For any two pairs `(ai,bi)∈L` and `(aj,bj)∈L` such that 1≤i≤j≤n , we have (at least) one of three cases:

- ai=aj and bi=bj
- ai < aj
- bi < bj

For example, the list `L=[(1,2),(1,1)]` would not be valid. An example of a valid list is:

```
L = [(0,1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 3), (4, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 5)]
```

**The question is**: Write a recursive function that applies the divide-and-conquer paradigm to search if a given pair of values (x, y) is in L.

The following is my python code which doesn't work as expected:

```
def pair_search(l, p):
    found = False
    calls = 1

    if len(l) == 0:
        return found, calls
    if len(l) == 1:
        if l[0] == p:
            found = True
        return found, calls

    mid = len(l) // 2

    if p == l[mid]:
        found = True
        return found, calls
    elif (l[mid][0] == p[0] and l[mid][1] == p[1]) or l[mid][0] < p[0] or l[mid][1] < p[1]:
        f, c = pair_search(l[mid + 1:], p)   
    else:
        f, c = pair_search(l[:mid], p)
    found = f or found
    calls += c
    return found, calls
```

Comment: If you trying to apply binary search, you firstly should sort `L`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always pick one half, but in some cases you can't know which half to search in. You can do the following to fix it:

```
def pair_search(l, p):
    if not l:
        return False, 1
    mid = len(l) // 2
    m = l[mid]  # pair in the middle
    if p == m:
        return True, 1
    if p[0] <= m[0] and p[1] <= m[1]:  
        # both smaller (or equal), must be in lower half
        f, c = pair_search(l[:mid], p)
        return f, c + 1 
    if p[0] >= m[0] and p[1] >= m[1]:  
        # both bigger (or equal), must be in upper half
        f, c = pair_search(l[mid+1:], p)
        return f, c + 1 
    # one smaller, one bigger: could be in either half
    f1, c1 = pair_search(l[:mid], p)
    if f1:  # found, so don't look any further
        return f1, c1 + 1
    f2, c2 = pair_search(l[mid+1:], p)
    return f2, c1 + c2 + 1
```

Comment: Glad to help. Updated with greater/less **or equal** in the conditions to reduce some calls.